# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) MVC JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post 2 param from a view with JavaScript to Controler but i`m getting this error. Dont know why..
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

**transfer.js**

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#transferPlayerButton").click(function () {`

```
    var playerId = document.getElementById("id_player").value;
    var teamId = document.getElementById("id_team").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Player/TransferPlayer',
        data:
            {
                playerId: playerId,
                newTeamId: teamId
            },
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        }


    });

});
```

`});`

**controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TransferPlayer(int playerId, int newTeamId)
    {
        return Content(string.Format("Player {0} it is now at team {1}.", playerId, newTeamId)); 
    }
```

and this is my view. I'have been mapped object to database obj but i cand figure out why im getting this 500 error. Need some help. I`m a newbie in mvc/javascript

```
  @model FotballTeamsProject.Models.PlayerModels.PlayerTransferModel


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Player/Transfer.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var transferUrl= "@Url.Action("TransferPlayer", "Player")";
    </script>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nume</th>
        <th>Prenume</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Skill</th>
        <th>Valoare</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Echipa Actuala</th>
        <th style="margin-right: 10px;">Echipa Viitoare</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

        <tr>
            <td id="id_player">@Model.Player.id_player</td>
            <td>@Model.Player.player_firstname</td>
            <td>@Model.Player.player_surname</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@Model.Player.player_skill</td>

            <td>@Model.Player.player_value</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@Model.Player.name_team</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <select id="id_team">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">Fara echipa</option>
                    @foreach (var teamInfo in Model.Teams)
                    {
                        <option value="@teamInfo.Key">@teamInfo.Value</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
          </tr>

</table>
</tbody>
    <p>
        <input id="transferPlayerButton" type="button" value="Transfera" />
    </p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the root cause, but .value on a table cell won't give you the value of id_player, you should use innerText instead. This may be causing playerId to be null in your post.  Have you tried putting a breakpoint on your Action method and debugging?  Is your breakpoint hit?  What are the values of the parameters if it is?

Comment: yes, i put a breakpoint and it isn`t hit..

Comment: first put your js `Transfer.js` just before end of the body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AJAX call, pass the data like so:

`data: JSON.stringify({ playerId: playerId, newTeamId: teamId }),`

When posting the data as you are, it looks like this:

`playerId=1&newTeamId=2`

But in your AJAX setup the `contentType` is set to 'application/json;charset=utf-8' which means the data should be passed in JSON format. Because the data is not being passed in JSON format, the MVC model binder is unable to do it's job and get the data from the request body (since it thought there was JSON data coming along the wite, due to the `contentType`).

When you use JSON.stringify the data will be passed like this in the request body:

```
{
    newTeamId: "2"
    playerId: "1"
}
```

Comment: I'm able to sent param newTeamId param right now but playerId isn't working, i dont know why but i will figure out. thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify()` as per my answer? That does work, I tired it myself just now. Save yourself the hassle, give `JSON.stringify()` a go first.

Comment: Yes, worked, i had a little problem at  var playerId = $("#id_player").html(); i wasnt pay attention. Thank you

Comment: If my answer worked for you, do you mind marking it as the correct answer, so that other people who may get the same problem know which solution worked for you. Cheers.